# Regular expression to collect everything after final matching pattern

Tags: regex

I have a list of strings like this:

- This is [xxxx] a string [yyyy] and this is more of it.
- This is [yyyy]
  also a string [xxxx] and this is more of it.

I'm trying to automate splitting the strings on the positions marked by `[xxxx]` and `[yyyy]`. I am currently able to extract the pre-`[xxxx]` or `[yyyy]` text using the expression `^.*?(?=\[(xxxx|yyyy)\])`. I can extract the middle part of the text using the expression `(?<=\[(xxxx|yyyy)\]).*?(?=\[(xxxx|yyyy)\])`.

However, I cannot figure out how to extract the final part of the text, following the final occurrence of either `[xxxx]` or `[yyyy]`. Using `(?<=\[(xxxx|yyyy)\]).*` gives me everything after the *first* occurrence of either `[xxxx]` or `[yyyy]` (i.e., like `a string [yyyy] and this is more of it.`). Using a single character exclusion here won't work either (i.e., something like `[^xy\[\]]*$`, since I don't want to target xs and ys that are parts of actual words in the string (which doesn't occur in the examples above, but there might be some cases in my actual dataset). Most of the other questions I've seen about this are targeting everything after a specific word or everything after a specific character, which doesn't apply to this case (since I want to match everything after the final occurrence of either of the matching expressions).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

And of course, as soon as I post this I figure something out. I'm able to use `.*(?<=\[(xxxx|yyyy)\])(.*?)$` and what I want is in the last group.